# How to perform correct loop for Multiplication quiz

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, math, infinite-loop

I'm new to programming and would like some help.

I'm trying to create a Multiplication quiz that loops infinitely until the user inputs no. Also, when a multiplication problem is presented the program must also display rather or not the user input is correct.

When the user inputs no the loop will stop and display how many correct answers out of the total amount of questions asked.

any ideas?

**Here is my code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int correctCount = 0; // count the number correct question
    int count = 0; // count the number of question
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   // 2 random single-digit int
    int number1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    int number2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);

   do {
     // prompt the student to answer "what is number1 - number2
     System.out.print("What is " + number1 + " * " + number2 + "?");
     int answer = input.nextInt();

     // grade the answer and display the result
     if (number1 * number2 == answer) {
        System.out.println("You are correct!");
        correctCount++; // increase the correct answer count
     } else {
        System.out.println("Your answer is worng. \n" + number1 + " * "
                + number2 + " should be: " + (number1 * number2));
     }

     count++;

     System.out.println("\nWould you like more questions?");
     System.out.print(" Y or N ?");
     String option = input.nextLine();
 } while (input.equals('y'));
    System.out.println("\nYou've answered " + correctCount + " out of "
        + count + " Correct");
}
```

I know my code is a bit of a mess because I tried to perform do-while loop but wasn't able to get my program to run correctly.

Comment: What is your exact problem with the current code?

Comment: `input.equals('y')` should probably be something like `option.equalsIgnoreCase("y")` instead.

Comment: @MickMnemonic using .equalsIgnoreCase("y") helped, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your do-while loop condition is `while(input.equals('y'))`, but `input` is a `Scanner` object, which doesn't work in this loop. Since you read in the user's choice to continue into `option`, It should be `while(option.equals("y"))`, or better still, `while(option.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))`, which will let the user enter `y` or `Y`

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is that you are checking to see if the value of `input` equals "y" which it doesn't because input is a Scanner not a String.

In order to make this work there are a few changes you need to make.

First you want to choose the random numbers inside the do loop, otherwise you will get the same numbers over and over again.

Second, you want to move the declaration of the `option` String outside the loop so that it will have the right scope to be usable.

Third you need to call `input.nextLine()` after getting the `answer` int because the nextInt() method only gets the int, leaving the rest of the line.

Fourth you want to use `.trim()` when getting the next line to remove whitespace and newline chars.

Finally when checking the value of option use the `.equalsIgnoreCase()` so that it will work for upper or lowercase y.

```
        int correctCount = 0; // count the number correct question
        int count = 0; // count the number of question
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);



        String option;

        do {
            //2 random single-digit int
            int number1 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
            int number2 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);  

            //prompt the student to answer "what is number1 - number2
            System.out.print("What is " + number1 + " * " + number2 + "?");
            int answer = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();

            //grade the answer and display the result
            if (number1 * number2 == answer)
            {
                System.out.println("You are correct!");
                correctCount++; //increase the correct answer count

            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Your answer is worng. \n" + 
            number1 + " * " + number2 + " should be: " + (number1 * number2));
            }

            count++;

            System.out.println("\nWould you like more questions?");
            System.out.print(" Y or N ?");

            option = input.nextLine().trim();
        } while (option.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
```

Comment: Thanks, everything managed to work. adding option as an string really help. I should have figured to do so. Seems like i had the right idea just executed properly.

Comment: yeah you were definitely on the right track just a couple little things

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what is going wrong with the scanner, but I updated your class and it is now working fine.  I moved the random numbers within the loop so the numbers change for each iteration.  I also changed the while condition to be "input.next().equalsIgnoreCase("y")".  When it is input.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("y") it stops on one iteration.  I'm not familiar with the oddities of the Scanner class and would personally just use a Reader.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int correctCount = 0; // count the number correct question
        int count = 0; // count the number of question
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            //2 random single-digit int
            int number1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            int number2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);

            //prompt the student to answer "what is number1 - number2
            System.out.print("What is " + number1 + " * " + number2 + "?");
            int answer = input.nextInt();

            //grade the answer and display the result
            if (number1 * number2 == answer) {
                System.out.println("You are correct!");
                correctCount++; //increase the correct answer count

            } else {
                System.out.println("Your answer is worng. \n" +
                        number1 + " * " + number2 + " should be: " + (number1 * number2));
            }

            count++;

            System.out.println("\nWould you like more questions?");
            System.out.print(" Y or N ?");
        } while (input.next().equalsIgnoreCase("y"));


        System.out.println("\nYou've answered " + correctCount + " out of " + count
                + " Correct");
    }
}
```